# How build a website on blockchain to prevent it from blocking in some countries?

Tags: ip, blockchain, firewall

I know that my question is general and can have tons of answers, but I couldn't find any guide or tutorial on the internet.

Think of China, North-Korea or other restricted countries which block millions of websites or IPs. is there a way to build a website based on blockchain or other technologies to prevent it from being blocked?

Answer (score 0):

A blockchain may not be suitable for serving HTML content because web pages are usually huge compared to a transaction data. There are other alternatives such as IPFS (InterPlanetary File System), based on a P2P protocol to share files in a decentralized manner.
However, blockchains can be used in conjunction to provide a decentralized name service (e.g., namecoin) or incentivizing storage on IPFS nodes (e.g., filecoin).

Answer (score 0):

Idea of blocking certain things on a blockchain network is essentially contrary to the original idea of peer-to-peer networks.
But if you are willing to do it you'd have to find a way to host a website on the blockchain. e.g: [Codius](https://codius.org/)  by [Stefan Thomas](https://twitter.com/justmoon)

There's even an example of hosting a simple [react-app](https://medium.com/codius/running-a-simple-react-app-on-the-codius-smart-contract-platform-7ddefce8cb06)